# How to structure scripture-based lookups in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

My objective is to provide chapter/verse-based searching functionality.  I'll have content that has a book, chapter and verse references associated with it.    I'd like for the searcher to be able to find content via search terms like:

- `Luke` - matches all results for that book
- `Luke 1`- all for book/chapter
- `Luke 1-5` - all for book and chapters in between
- `Luke 1:13` - any content that has this chapter/verse within its range
- `Luke 1:2-7` - any content that has this verse range within its range of scripture

To accomplish this with mysql using `LIKE '%%'` and such can be very tricky, requires a decent amount of complexity with relations and just doesn't seem like the right solution.

Elasticsearch seems like it's likely a much better approach for this kind of thing but I'm hoping to get some input from an experienced dev on how they would accomplish this from a data structure perspective.

Is the best approach to store each individual verse that's possible (Luke 1:2, Luke 1:3, Luke 1:4) or is there a way for me to just tell elastic search the verse range (verses 2-4) and it'll do the work for me?

Comment: how are you modelling your data models for elastic. can you please share some models

Comment: @user3775217 I don't know yet, that's part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need a thin layer logic to convert those search queries to Elasticsearch filters. There might be better solutions than this (I haven't worked so much with analyzed fields and Lucene) but this is what comes to my mind.

First option is to create 1 document / verse, which would create about 31k documents which isn't that many. This is the simplest data model to query.

> There are 23,145 verses in the Old Testament and 7,957 verses in the
>   New Testament. This gives a total of 31,102 verses

```
{
  "book": "Luke"
  "chapter": 1,
  "verse": 13,
  "contents": "But the angel said to him: Do not be afraid, Zechariah; your prayer has been heard. Your wife Elizabeth will bear you a son, and you are to call him John."
}
```

(I dislike having field called `"text"` as it is also a keyword on ES mappings.)

An other option is to store verses as nested documents, you'd get 1 document / chapter:

```
{
  "book": "Luke"
  "chapter": 1,
  "verses": [
    {
      "verse": 12,
      "contents": "..."
    },
    {
      "verse": 13,
      "contents": "But the angel said to him: Do not be afraid, Zechariah; your prayer has been heard. Your wife Elizabeth will bear you a son, and you are to call him John."
    },
    {
      "verse": 14,
      "contents": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Third option is to have one document / book:

```
{
  "book": "Luke"
  "verses": [
    {
      "chapter": 1,
      "verse": 12,
      "contents": "..."
    },
    {
      "chapter": 1,
      "verse": 13,
      "contents": "But the angel said to him: Do not be afraid, Zechariah; your prayer has been heard. Your wife Elizabeth will bear you a son, and you are to call him John."
    },
    {
      "chapter": 1,
      "verse": 14,
      "contents": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Actually nested documents count as documents as well, and because they only share the `"book"` field with root document you don't gain much by nesting them. So I'd go with the option #1.

I don't know if ES/Lucene supports some form of tagging parts of texts like this, then you'd only have one document / book. Storing page numbers is a similar problem and people suggested to just store 1 document / page.

**Update:**

Based on my usage of Kibana I think I can construct a valid [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "book:\"Luke\" AND chapter:3 AND verse:[5 TO 13]",
      "use_dis_max" : false
    }
  }
}
```

In my understanding [dis_max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) is relevant only in "search" (scoring and ranking) context but here we are just filtering for exact matches so it can be set to `false`.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!  Would you mind giving me an example of how you'd query using #1?  I'm trying to wrap my mind around the value added by using ElasticSearch over MySQL.  Specifically I'd like to understand if it will handle the verse range portion of the search or of I'd still need to do that myself somehow if I used ES.

Comment: I added an example, but as there are only 31k verses and all of your examples are trivial to implement in SQL I'm not sure if ES would bring you any benefits. It would support more interesting use cases such as "significant terms" aggregation (see which words are more frequently used in Luke's book when compared to others) and free text search of verses.

Comment: Thanks Niko, I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this scenario from your experience!